# How to run my app with root privileges on macOS?

Tags: c++, macos

I am working on a simple C/C++ project in which I have to collect a bunch of files from a bunch of macOS specific directories.
But some directories/files require root access.
I know that I can open it from the terminal.
But I want to know if there is a way to elevate to root when the app starts.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to access files without the correct file permissions for that user.

Comment: Can't I elevate the app's privileges to root  in order to access for example /private/var/db/launchd.db/subfolders?

Comment: You could run with sudo basically giving the progress root access, this would give your program access to all the files on the system.

Comment: I know that I can run it with sudo.
But I want something that prompts the user for their password and uses it to grant access in those locked directories.

Comment: https://github.com/michaelvobrien/OSXSimpleAuth/wiki - This is a guide on asking for root access on OSX. I haven't used it myself but looks complete. Also has examples

Comment: Thank you for your time! I will look at it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/815725)

Comment: Umm, ```sudo``` ***does*** prompt the user for their password and grant root access. Why is it not an acceptable answer?

Comment: I want to ask the user for their password with the authorization plugin ( with a GUI ), not from the terminal.